# Pop message from channel in Redis

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis, publish-subscribe

I need to publish messages on one machine(setter) in specific channel and get it on other machines(handlers). The problem is that each handler should process unique message.

As I can see in [documentation](http://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), there is no standard method to pop messages from channel, maybe I try to use it in wrong way?

Here is code of handler:

```
 import redis

 r=redis.Redis()
 pubsub = r.pubsub()
 pubsub.subscribe('test_channel')
 for item in self.pubsub.listen():
    ...
```

Here is the code of setter:

```
import redis

r = redis.Redis()
r.publish('test_channel', 'test message')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pub/Sub doesn't fit this pattern - look into using a List and call blocking pop operations in the handlers instead.